# Align ImageView & TextView inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, imageview, alignment, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout and inside, a ImageView and TextView. I want to align the center of the LinearLayout the ImageView and the TextView below the ImageView.

I only get the top align ImageView in LinearLayout. How I can do?

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/boton"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/plano"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Plano"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show you how to do the same taking advantage of a RelativeLayout and a TextView's compoundDrawable:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/plano"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:text="Plano"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Compound drawables help keeping down the View count, and therefore intrinsically speed up the layout

The key is `android:drawableTop="@drawable/plano"` This replaces the top image.
You can also set a Right, Left, Bottom side image.
Even all together.

Comment: my image has to be 90x90

Comment: It's not a matter of size. You can put whatever-sized image inside. You need to provide your image 90x90 for the mdpi resoulution, 180x180 for the xhdpi resolution and so on (0.75, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4 - meanning ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi scaling factor).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the "layout_gravity" field as "center_horizontal" but the two widgets (ImageView, TextView).

Here code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:text="Small Text"
      android:id="@+id/textView" 
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the ImageView not see to center