# Center image view and text view in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-linearlayout

I want the search text below the search icon. The search icon + text group should be centered on the screen.

What I *want*:____________What the screen *actually* looks like:

[image]
[image]

**Note:** I used Linear Layout because I need the List View directly underneath. It will be used for the search bar. For those suggesting using TextView's `android:drawableTop`, I tried that but the image is so small (even when I set the image to 500px) vs when I set the image as "100dpx100dp" in an image view.

**Code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_gray_500px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search_hint"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="130dp"
            tools:text="@string/search_hint" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25431178/7327018)

Comment: and what about listview where to place listview than

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below code will solve your issue :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/app_logo_main" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/searchTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use only TextView, in TextView one attribute is there drawableTop, use that for image. If you want some spacing between the Image and the Text, then use drawablePadding.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_search_gray_500px"
            android:text="@string/search_hint"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true />

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="searchTextView"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that but the image is so small (even when I set the image to 500px) vs when I set the image as "100dpx100dp" in an image view - not sure why

Answer (score 2):

**Try this** :

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/searchTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/search_hint"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />




</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`RelativeLayout`**.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlROOT"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_gray_500px" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
              />
       </RelativeLayout>

       <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlROOT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of different ImageVIew we can use android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_search_gray_500px"
What you think.

Comment: @Shekhar No Problem.